# adding a facebook-like plugin on a kentico page

Tags: asp.net, facebook, kentico

The normal aspnet way will not work properly as the public web site pages uses page routing and the real page name will be linked to.

Is there a way that i can add the facebook like plugin to a kentico page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to grab the CurrentNodeAlias path using the Kentico API. I also grab the domain using standard aspnet properties

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=138739939541536&amp;xfbml=1"></script><fb:like href="<%= Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) +CMS.CMSHelper.CMSContext.CurrentAliasPath%>" send="false" layout="box_count" width="110" show_faces="false" font=""></fb:like>
```

Note: you will need to add in the namespace for fb in the  element something like:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

Note: you have to use the FB like button. This is by design as a security concern.